# Winforms reading data from excel table with specific columns

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to read data from an excel table which this piece of code performs perfectly 
However, this will read all columns from the table which I don't need, I only need specific columns from the excel table

```
            int fabricHeaderRow = findFabricHeader(excelRange); //row number 26

            int rows = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int cols = excelRange.Columns.Count;
            myNewRow3 = null;
            for (int i = fabricHeaderRow + 2; i <= rows; i++)
            {
                myNewRow3 = bomTable.NewRow();

                if (excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null) //Checks that the item column isn't empty
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++)
                    {
                        if (excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 == null)
                        {
                            myNewRow3[j - 1] = string.Empty; //inserts empty string into datagrid row[i] if the cell is empty
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myNewRow3[j - 1] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (myNewRow3 != null)
                    {
                        bomTable.Rows.Add(myNewRow3); //adds a new row to datable if not null
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    break; //break out of the outer for-loop as it reached an empty excel row
                }
            }
```

[Excel table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeUNb.png)
For example, from the table, I only need ID, COLOR, DESCRIPTION, SUPPILER and COST columns in my datarow, I'm stuck at trying to figure out how to read specific columns with multiple rows into a datarow.

```
public string[] bomArr = { "ID", "COLOR", "DESCRIPTION", "SUPPLIER", "COST"};
//for loop here
if (bomArr.Any(x => excelRange.Cells[27, j].Value2.Equals(x))){
myNewRow[currentCount] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString(); //string
currentCount++;
}
```

I'm thinking of trying this, basically it'll only add to the datarow if any values in the array matches with a column header. But I only can make it work for tables with a single row, multiple rows make it more complicated.

Comment: Don't use the inner loop and get your data directly indexing the columns that your need?

Comment: Wait wdym, I thought using a nested for-loop is necessary in order to read multiple rows from a table?

Comment: With the outer one you are going through on all rows, with the inner one on all columns.